# no route matches [GET] "/logout"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'users#index'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
end

<% if logged_in? %>
    <li><%= link_to "Sign out", logout_path, method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

GemFile

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'turbolinks'


//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Is this a javascript issue? It does not seem to want to recognize method: :delete?

Here is my application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Workspace</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there an alternative way to pass method: :delete to the route?

Comment: DO you see it when u do rakes routes ?

Comment: yes, it is there

Comment: Do you see any Javascript errors in the developer console in your browser?

Comment: Provide the console logging and error stack please. Also include the HTML generated from your link.

Comment: Maybe you have javascript disabled: ["Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET"](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

Comment: You can use `<%= button_to "Sign out", logout_path, method: :delete %>` to generate a discrete form that works even without JS.

Comment: @max that works max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While shipping apps with broken javascript is not a good idea it can make sense to harden certain critical aspects of your app like logout by using `button_to` instead of `link_to`.

`button_to "foo", bar method: delete` and `link_to "foo", bar method: delete` both achieve the same goal - the request is sent as a POST request with the special `_method` param used by  `Rack::MethodOverride` to set the request method to PATCH, DELETE etc.

`button_to` creates an actual form containing hidden inputs and a single button. `link_to` uses javascript (Rails UJS) to create a virtual form  and posts the form when the user clicks the link.

Answer (score 2):

One of two things is happening:

1. The `<a>` element rendered doesn't contain the `data-method` attribute for UJS to latch onto. Perhaps there's a stale version cached or you're looking at a different view? Easiest way to check is to pop into your web inspector or view source and confirm the presence of the attribute on the relevant link.
2. UJS isn't handling the click on the element. This could be due to a JS error halting execution, but it could also be another click handler you have registered taking precedence. Check your JS console for errors to eliminate that as a potential cause, and if not, verify that the UJS script is in your “sources” panel:

   [image]

   If it's present, and the behavior is the same, try adding a breakpoint on the `handleMethod` function in UJS and running again. If it's triggered, step through to see what happens that's resulting in failure. If it's not triggered, you can back up from there and look at other handlers on the link.

   [[image: breakpoint]]

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand why you believe it to be a javascript issue. I think you need something like the following:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
    <li>
        <%= link_to logout_path, method: :delete do %>
            <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Sign Out
        <% end %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The `jquery_ujs` JS library is responsible for making it a `delete` request, hence the JS issue. I don't think your proposal will fix the issue.